# Bayesian inference of mean of Multivariate Gaussian

Tags: self-study, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution, likelihood

Text of the problem I have to solve..

State the generic case of a Bayesian treatment of the parameters $\theta$ used to model the data, i.e., $p(  \theta |   X,   Y)$. 
Derive the estimate of the mean, assuming that the model of the output variable is a Gaussian distribution with a fixed variance.
Which are the advantages of being Bayesian?

My (incomplete) answer:

As always we use the maximul likelihood approach:

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{arg}\max_{  \theta} \log P(  \theta |   X,   Y) =  \mathrm{arg}\max_{  \theta} \log P(  Y |  X,  \theta)P(  \theta).
\end{equation}

We could assume $P(  \theta)$ normal distributed with $0$ mean and $\Sigma_{  \theta}$  as standard deviation. As we assume the data i.i.d, we could derive:

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{arg} \max_{  \theta} \sum_i \log P(y_i |  X,   \theta) + \log P(  \theta).
\end{equation}

Now, since we also have assumed the output distributed as Gaussian, we will end up in the following:

\begin{equation}
 \mathrm{arg}\max_{  \mu} \sum_i - \frac{1}{2} \log(2^d \pi^d |\Sigma|) - \frac{1}{2}  (X-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (X-  \mu)  - \frac{1}{2} \log(2^d \pi^d |\Sigma_{  \mu}|) - \frac{1}{2}  (\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mu)
\end{equation}

where $d$ is the number of features. Since the function is convex, we could use the gradient:

\begin{equation}
 \nabla{  \mu} \sum_i - \frac{1}{2} \log(2^d \pi |\Sigma|) - \frac{1}{2}  (y_i-\mu)\Sigma (y_i-  \mu)^T  - \frac{1}{2} \log(2^d \pi |\Sigma_{  \mu}|) - \frac{1}{2}  (\mu)\Sigma (\mu)^T = 0
\end{equation}
thus:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{  \mu}  \sum_i  - \frac{1}{2}   (y_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1} (y_i-  \mu)  - \frac{1}{2}    (\mu)^T\Sigma_{  \mu}^{-1} (\mu) = 0.
\end{equation}
We already know how to compute $\nabla_{  \mu} (y_i-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (y_i-  \mu)$ and $(  \mu)\Sigma_{  \mu} (  \mu)^T$:

\begin{equation}
 \sum_i     (y_i-\mu)^T (\Sigma^{-1}+ \Sigma^{-T})  +  (\mu)^T (\Sigma_{  \mu}^{-1} + \Sigma_{  \mu}^{-T}) = 0,
\end{equation}

considering $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma_{\mu}$ be symmetric then

\begin{equation}
 \sum_i  (y_i-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}  +  (\mu)^T \Sigma_{  \mu}^{-1} = 0
\end{equation}

which yelds:

\begin{equation}
  - N \mu^T \Sigma^{-1}   + N (\mu)^T \Sigma_{  \mu}^{-1} + \sum_i  y_i^T \Sigma^{-1} = 0.
\end{equation}

We must isolate $\mu^T$

\begin{equation}
  + N \mu^T   - N (\mu)^T \Sigma_{  \mu}^{-1} \Sigma  = \sum_i  y_i^T 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    (\mu)^T (I- \Sigma_{  \mu}^{-1} \Sigma ) = \frac{\sum_i  y_i^T}{N}
\end{equation}

From here I can't go further. I don't even know if till here it is correct what I did.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. The question is too vague as stated, in particular the difference between $X$ and $Y$ is not spelled out. There is no $y_i$ in your developed equations.
2. It is unclear why you follow a maximisation path when the question does not mention MAP (maximum a posteriori). A more natural approach would be to seek the posterior mean (provided it is well-defined).
3. Seeking directly the posterior distribution on $\mu$ is actually simpler. This is how the problem is processed in Bayesian textbooks (like [ours](http://amzn.to/2kxP1vO)).
4. What is the meaning of $-$ in $\Sigma_{\mu}^{-T}$?

Comment: 1) I assume $Y$ i.i.d thus $P(Y | X, \theta) = \prod_i P(y_i | X, \theta)$. 2) could you provide an example? 3) - same as 2) . 4) $\Sigma_{\mu}^{-T} = (\Sigma_{\mu}^{T})^{-1}$. P.S. I found many typos, now I'll correct them.

Comment: 2-3) check textbooks. 4) $\Sigma_\mu$ is a symmetric matrix, you do not need the transpose sign. There are still typos in the formulas, like confusion between the different covariance matrices.